# Error mostrando preview Angular 8+NodeJS 11.10

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, angular8

Mi problema radica a la hora de mostrar la imagen subida, donde se actualiza el **preview** de la foto del médico. La foto se sube bien al servidor, pero el **preview** da error porque no encuentra un término dado. Trabajé la muestra del **preview** con un *EventEmitter* en mi servicio **ModalUploadService** llamandolo desde mi **ngOnInit()** en mi componente **Medico**:

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this._modalUploadService.notificacion
      .subscribe( resp => {
        console.log( resp );
        this.medico.img = resp.medico.img;
      } )
  }
```

El campo donde está la foto de perfil del médico y al dar clic sobre el llama a un **Modal** que contiene el formulario de subir la imagen:

```
<img (click)="cambiarFoto()" [src]="medico.img | imagen: 'medicos'" class="img-circle img-fluid pointer">
```

El código de la funcion **cambiarFoto()**:

```
cambiarFoto() {
    this._modalUploadService.mostrarModal( 'medicos', this.medico._id );
  }
```

El servicio **UploadService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URL_SERVICIOS } from "../../config/config";

@Injectable( {
  providedIn: 'root'
} )
export class SubirArchivoService {

  constructor() {
  }

  subirArchivo( archivo: File, tipo: string, id: string ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

      let formData = new FormData();
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      formData.append( 'imagen', archivo, archivo.name );

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
          if( xhr.status === 200 ) {
            console.log( 'Imagen Subida' );

            resolve( xhr.response );
          } else {
            console.log( 'Fallo la subida' );

            reject( xhr.response );
          }
        }
      };

      let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/upload/' + tipo + '/' + id;

      xhr.open( 'PUT', url, true );
      xhr.send( formData );

    } );
  }
}
```

El servicio **ModalUploadService**:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable( {
  providedIn: 'root'
} )
export class ModalUploadService {

  public tipo: string;
  public id: string;

  public oculto: string = 'oculto';
  public notificacion = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
    console.log( 'modal upload listo' )
  }

  ocultarModal() {
    this.oculto = 'oculto';
    this.id = null;
    this.tipo = null;
  }

  mostrarModal( tipo: string, id: string ) {
    this.oculto = '';
    this.id = id;
    this.tipo = tipo;
  }
}
```

El código de *backend-server* para subir las imagenes ejecuta a la perfección, (todo probado dese **Postman**), por lo que no creo que el error sea allí.

Este es el error que da cuando tiene que actualizar el *preview* y como se puede ver en la consola de depuración si se esta mandando el **img** desde desde el response:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entre varios testeos logré encontrar la solución al problema, el response siempre llegaba vacío o indefinido, entonces opté por recargar el objeto **Medico** completo, en vez de solo la imagen.

En mi ngOnInit() :

```
ngOnInit() {

            this._modalUploadService.notificacion
              .subscribe( resp => {

               //Mi solucion para el error del response cambie 
               // this.medico.img = resp.medico.img; por  this.cargarMedico(this.medico._id )

                 this.cargarMedico( this.medico._id );  
                 Swal.fire('Imagen actualizada', 'usuario update', 'success');
                }
              )
          }
```